# Why can't I pass an UninterpretedBytes to a void* thru DLL/C-Connect?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I'd like to pass an UninterpretedBytes to an external library, say something like this

```
MyLibrary>>foo: buf len: len
    <C: int foo(void *buf,unsigned int len)>

MyApplication>>test
    buffer := UninterpretedBytes new: 4.
    ^MyLibrary new foo: buffer len: buffer size.
```

But this fails in `CPointerType>>coerceForArgument:anObject`.

I know that I could use `buffer gcCopyToHeap` but I don't want to.
I want to handle an object in Smalltalk memory with Smalltalk 1-based address and no extra copy nor any other complication.

I find the last lines of `CPointerType>>coerceForArgument:anObject` suspiscious:

```
(anObject isString
    or: [self isOopRef and: [anObject class isBits and: [anObject class isVariable]]])
        ifTrue: [^anObject].
```

`self isOopRef` means that the CPointerType has been declared as `_oopref *`.
If I cheat and declare:

```
MyLibrary>>foo: buf len: len
    <C: int foo(_oopref *buf,unsigned int len)>
```

then `MyApplication new test` works as expected, but I don't want to cheat, the prototypes are extracted automatically from C headers and I don't want to patch them manually.

`self isOopRef` semantically means is a reference to an Object Oriented Pointer.
Every Object can be viewed as an Object Oriented Pointer and can thus be passed by reference to such `_oopref *`, except immediate objects like SmallInteger SmallDouble Character. There is a guard above in code to check for the case when `anObject isImmediate`, so at this stage, `anObject` is definitely an oop.

Such _oopref could be manipulated from within the external C-code, for example thru some Object Engine function oe*(), and this is not limited to arrays of bytes/words/double words!
The guard `and: [anObject class isBits and: [anObject class isVariable]]` thus makes no sense.

If I modify the last lines of `CPointerType>>coerceForArgument:anObject` into:

```
(anObject isString
    or: [self isOopRef or: [anObject class isBits and: [anObject class isVariable]]])
        ifTrue: [^anObject].
```

Then `MyApplication new test` works like a charm.
Wasn't it the real intention? Pass either any kind of non immediate object if the prototype specifies a pointer to an oop, or pass a reference to an array of bytes/words/...

Comment: I'm not a VisualWorks user, but have you considered the case where the object moves (and therefore its oop changes) in the course of the call? This could happen, for example, if the external function has a callback to Smalltalk.

Comment: Yes, there are two possible path of failure due to relocation, callback and threaded FFI calls. VW provides a way to allocate  the buffer argument in FixedSpace, a space in Smalltalk memory exempt from relocation. I understand that it's user responsibility to allocate in correct space. It's also possible to specify that the external function requires a pointer in FixedSpace by manually patching function prototype with adhoc qualifier, and that is later checked by CPointerType>>coerceForArgument:. I want to be in charge of responsibility and assume it.

Comment: Contrarily to what I wrote above, and unlike beOopRef which is triggered by _oopref qualifier there is no qualifier connected to beFixed, and it seems that this facility to ensure that the actual argument is really in FixedSpace is unused in the system, and not easily accessible.

Comment: There is potentially another issue: alignment. ExtenalLibrary function might expect some alignment of passed address on 4 8 or 16 bytes. The alignment of Smalltalk bits array data may differ. I had problems in legacy squeak-vm when trying to pass a double *data, that was sometimes aligned on 4 bytes instead of 8...

Comment: It seems that _oopref is designed for passing a direct pointer to object data, as opposed to _oop which is for passing a pointer to object header. Object engine functions oe*() require _oop, not _oopref.

Comment: Good point! I hadn't realized that there could be an alignment issue too.

Comment: there is no qualifier for beFixed, but from the comment in coerceForArgument: there probably used to be one: >>If the receiver is tagged __fixed then fail if the argument is not already at a fixed address.